# Lualatex/Japanese document compiles fine in TeXstudio, but not MacTex

Tags: luatex, mactex, japanese

I'm having trouble compiling the following document.

I have done a fresh install of MacOS 10.14 and installed the full size MacTex 2018 distribution directly from TUG. I have also upgraded all packages using the TexLive Utility.

Then, I installed TexStudio 2.12.14 from MacPorts and tried to compile the following document:

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2015 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}      
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\moderncvstyle{classic}                             
\moderncvcolor{grey}                               

\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\setmainjfont[BoldFont=IPAexGothic]{IPAexMincho} % \mcfamily
\setsansjfont{IPAexGothic} % \gtfamily
\newjfontfamily\jisninety[CJKShape=JIS1990]{IPAexMincho}
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{18}{20}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\fontsize{18}{20}\mdseries\upshape}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{footmisc} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.5cm}               
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} 
\newcolumntype{b}{X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.2\hsize}X}

\usepackage{booktabs}

% personal data
\name{芭蕉}{松尾} 
\address{123-3456}{日本語をかきましょう。}{日本語をかきましょう。}
\email{sth@mail.net}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------

\makecvtitle

\section{headline}

\cvitem{ghi}{\textit{this should actually compile just fine}}
\section{headline}
\cventry{00/2011 -- 03/2023}{Input}{More}{Input}{}{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item I studied.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{00/2011 -- 03/2023}{Input}{More}{Input}{}{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Stuff
\end{itemize}}

\section{headline}

\cventry{00/2011 -- 03/2023}{Input}{More}{Input}{}
{Stuff and stuff
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This is one.
        \item And another one.
    \end{itemize}}


\section{headline\footnotemark}
\cvitemwithcomment{日本語}{C1/C1/C1}{}

\footnotetext{This is a footnote}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error (scroll down):

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `JY3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/sl' undefined
(Font)              using `JY3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/n' instead on input line 52.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+lmr on input line 52.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmr.fd
File: ot1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OML+lmm on input line 52.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omllmm.fd
File: omllmm.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+lmsy on input line 52.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omslmsy.fd
File: omslmsy.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMX+lmex on input line 52.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omxlmex.fd
File: omxlmex.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <10> on input line 52.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 52.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 52.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JY3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 6.73553pt on input line 52.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JY3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 4.8111pt on input line 52.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-mvs.cfg
File: mt-mvs.cfg 2006/07/05 v1.1 microtype config. file: Marvosym Euro (RS)
)
\makecvheadpicturebox=\box113
\makecvheaddetailswidth=\skip88
\makecvheadpicturewidth=\skip89
\makecvheadnamebox=\box114

! Undefined control sequence.
MT@font@list .../sl/10 ,JT3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/n/10 
                                                  ,JY3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/n/10...
l.52 \makecvtitle

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JT3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 17.31995pt on input line 52.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JY3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 17.31995pt on input line 52.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <10.95> on input line 53.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 53.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 53.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JY3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.69775pt on input line 53.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JY3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.77332pt on input line 53.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JT3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 13.85594pt on input line 53.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JY3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 13.85594pt on input line 53.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `JT3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `JT3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/n' instead on input line 55.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JT3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.53629pt on input line 55.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `JY3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `JY3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/n' instead on input line 55.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `JT3/IPAexMincho(0)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `JT3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/n' instead on input line 60.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JT3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.53629pt on input line 60.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `JY3/IPAexMincho(0)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `JY3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/n' instead on input line 60.

(load cache: /Users/david/Library/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatexja/extra_lmromans
lant10-regular.luc)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JT3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/sl' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.53629pt on input line 60.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JY3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/sl' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.53629pt on input line 60.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JT3/IPAexMincho(0)/bx/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.53629pt on input line 64.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JY3/IPAexMincho(0)/bx/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.53629pt on input line 64.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\footnotemark' on input line 76.
```

And a bunch of warnings alongside the way:

- You have requested package `moderncvheadi', but the package provides`
  moderncvheadi'.
- Font shape `JT3/mc/m/it' undefined(Font) using`JT3/mc/m/n' instead
- Font shape `JT3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/sl' undefined(Font) using`
  JT3/IPAexMincho(0)/m/n' instead
- Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

I thought it had something to do with the font (IPAexMincho) not being present, but the package ipaex is actually installed (included in MacTex, although I'm not sure if that's the one I need, because in Linux the packages are named differently).

Also, this document here compiles perfectly fine, so it cannot be a missing font:

```
\documentclass{ltjsarticle}

\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeXGyreTermes}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeXGyreHeros}
\setmainjfont[BoldFont=IPAexGothic]{IPAexMincho}
\setsansjfont{IPAexGothic}
\newjfontfamily\jisninety[CJKShape=JIS1990]{IPAexMincho}

\begin{document}

mainのフォント．  {\bfseries boldのフォント．  }{\sffamily\gtfamily sansのフォント．  }

通常の「辻」．  {\jisninety JIS90字形の「辻」．  }


\end{document}
```

Help would be much appreciated :)

I have also tried to use another frontend, TexMaker 5.0.3 installed as dmg from the respective website.

Here is the corresponding file list to the first document, it is more up to date than on my Linux machine (which compiles fine):

```
 *File List*
moderncv.cls    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document cl
ass
  size11.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
etoolbox.sty    2018/08/19 v2.5f e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  luatex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for luatex
colortbl.sty    2018/12/12 v1.0d Color table columns (DPC)
   array.sty    2018/12/30 v2.4k Tabular extension package (FMi)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
   t1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
fancyhdr.sty    2019/01/31 v3.10 Extensive control of page headers and footers
tweaklist.sty    
    calc.sty    2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  xparse.sty    2018-10-17 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2019-02-15 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2019-02-15 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2019-02-15 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
microtype.sty    2018/01/14 v2.7a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
microtype-luatex.def    2018/01/14 v2.7a Definitions specific to luatex (RS)
microtype.cfg    2018/01/14 v2.7a microtype main configuration file (RS)
moderncvcollection.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 moderncv collections
moderncvcompatibility.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and lette
r compatibility patches
   babel.sty    2018/11/13 3.27 The Babel package
 ngerman.ldf    2018/12/08 v2.11 German support for babel (post-1996 orthography
)
moderncvstyleclassic.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter
 style scheme: classic
moderncviconsmarvosym.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and lette
r icons: marvosym
    tikz.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
     pgf.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
  pgfrcs.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
  pgfsys.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
moderncvheadi.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter header
 variant: 1
moderncvbodyi.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter body v
ariant: 1
    umvs.fd
moderncvcolorgrey.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter co
lor scheme: grey
luatexja-fontspec.sty    2019/01/28 fontspec support of LuaTeX-ja
l3keys2e.sty    2018-10-17 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
luatexja.sty    2019/01/28 Japanese Typesetting with Lua(La)TeX
luatexja-core.sty    2017/11/12 Core of LuaTeX-ja
luatexbase.sty    2015/10/04 v1.3 luatexbase interface to LuaTeX 
ctablestack.sty    2015/10/01 v1.0 Catcode table stable support
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/09/10 v0.29 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
everyhook.sty    2014/11/26 v1.2 (SVN Rev: 12)\ Hooks for low level TeX everyX p
rimitives.
svn-prov.sty    2010/04/24 v3.1862 Package Date/Version from SVN Keywords
ltj-base.sty    2017/05/05
ltj-latex.sty    2018/08/24 LaTeX support of LuaTeX-ja
lltjfont.sty    2019/01/29 Patch to NFSS2 for LuaTeX-ja
   tuenc.def    2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
everysel.sty    2011/10/28 v1.2 EverySelectfont Package (MS)
lltjdefs.sty    2019/02/11 Default font settings of LuaTeX-ja
lltjcore.sty    2018/06/15 Patch to LaTeX2e Kernel for LuaTeX-ja
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
lltjp-geometry.sty    2018/01/19 Patch to geometry for LuaTeX-ja with vertical w
riting mode
luatexja-compat.sty    2018/03/29 Compatibility with pTeX
fontspec.sty    2019/02/12 v2.7b Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
fontspec-luatex.sty    2019/02/12 v2.7b Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
   tuenc.def    2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
fontspec.cfg
luatexja-fontspec-26h.sty    2019/01/28 fontspec support of LuaTeX-ja
multicol.sty    2018/12/27 v1.8v multicolumn formatting (FMi)
fontawesome.sty    2016/05/15 v4.6.3.1 font awesome icons
fontawesomesymbols-generic.tex
fontawesomesymbols-xeluatex.tex
footmisc.sty    2011/06/06 v5.5b a miscellany of footnote facilities
geometry.sty    2018/04/16 v5.8 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
tabularx.sty    2016/02/03 v2.11b `tabularx' package (DPC)
 ltablex.sty    2014/08/13 v1.1 Modified tabularx
longtable.sty    2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)+ FMi change
    tabu.sty    2019/01/11 v2.9 - flexible LaTeX tabulars (FC+tabu-fixed)
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
booktabs.sty    2016/04/27 v1.618033 publication quality tables
hyperref.sty    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
luatex-loader.sty    2016/05/16 v0.6 Lua module loader (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
   puenc.def    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
 hluatex.def    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hyperref driver for luaTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
lltjp-array.sty    2018/03/29 Patch to array for LuaTeX-ja
lltjp-footmisc.sty    2017/05/05 Patch to footmisc for LuaTeX-ja
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
  mt-cmr.cfg    2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman (R
S)
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
20190421_test_CV.out
20190421_test_CV.out
  ot1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  omllmm.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omslmsy.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omxlmex.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  mt-mvs.cfg    2006/07/05 v1.1 microtype config. file: Marvosym Euro (RS)
 ***********
```

Comment: TeXstudio is a front end to a TeX distribution, while MacTeX *is* a TeX distribution. Please clarify what the problem is. Incidentally, why go thru homebrew if you could just [download the native MacOS version](https://www.texstudio.org/) of the program?

Comment: By the way, the "errors" you report -- other than the undefined `\makecvtitle` macro issue -- are *not* errors but only warnings. FWIW, I have MacTeX2018 as well, and I don't encounter a complaint about `\makecvtitle` being undefined when I compile your sample document.

Comment: Uninstall TeXStudio and dependents from MacPorts. Quite likely, the outdated TeX Live offered by MacPorts has been installed as well. Download TeXStudio from the website and live happier without MacPorts.

Comment: If you’re using `babel`, you can use its Japanese support.

Comment: To clarify, I use MacPorts because I originate from the Linux world and I'm used to using a centralized package manager whenever possible. So I installed MacTex the easy way from TUG, it went through without any errors. All I did was then install TexStudio from MacPorts. The problem now is, that the above mentioned document won't compile and I don't know why. As far as I can see in the dependencies, nothing else but TexStudio was pulled by MacPorts (and some QT dependencies of course...)

Comment: ... I also installed TexMaker.dmg from its website, but I get the same error message

Answer (score 0):

So the culprit was TeXlive 2018, everything works with TeXlive 2019 (pretest) (and 2017 for that matter).